# Create a BitBucket git commit hook?

Tags: git, bitbucket, githooks

I just ported over a repo from GitHub to BitBucket. Although it does many of necessities, I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to find documentation for creating a git commit hook.

Originally I had a ruby app on a CentOS server that was triggered by a GitHub hook. Does anyone know how to achieve the same in the BitBucket environment?

Thanks!

**Edit:** here's what the ruby app simply looks like if it helps:

```
post '/' do
  `rm -rf repofolder`
  `git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git`
  `sh fast_deploy.sh`
end
```

Comment: I wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18538247/1971120) to a similar issue a while ago. It is focused on Jenkins+BitBucket, but the blogs referenced there may give you some info. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. Although John Percival's answer is right, no current support for Ruby, the notification mechanism works.

The code for the Ruby app is in the question. Notice how it looks for a post via `post '/' do`. I was able to find support to send a POST to a URL in this neat find here: http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webhooks.html

Given that info, I was able to create a POST hook in BitBucket via:

1. Go to repo "admin" tab
2. Select "services"
3. Create a POST service to a special port on my URL `http://server.com:4567/`

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Write+brokers+%28hooks%29+for+Bitbucket

It looks like the BitBucket folks may not support Ruby, they do support a notification mechanism.

UPDATE:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Webhooks#ManageWebhooks-create_webhook

Comment: "We are no longer accepting new brokers. Please refer to the information below about using the POST service."

Comment: I think : https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Webhooks#ManageWebhooks-create_webhook will get to the same end state

Comment: yeah the first link is no bueno no more :(