# GitHub Deployment method on BitBucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Ive just started my journey into Source Control ... Im getting the hang of it using GIT.

I want to use a hosted repo to keep projects, i came across GitHub but I don't really want my projects public, so I have decided to go with Bitbucket.

One thing I did notice about GitHub though, is a script that automatically deploys when you do a commit to the server, basically you create a script that has the following code in it.

```
<?php `git pull`; ?>
```

Then go into the GitHub admin and point to this script in the Select Post-Receive URL section.

I was wondering if there is anything the same as this in Bitbucket as this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a BitBucket git commit hook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107320/create-a-bitbucket-git-commit-hook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitbucket offers the same functionality in the form of "services" that are run when you push changesets to the repository. See the [help for the POST service](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+Up+the+bitbucket+POST+Service) which is the one you're after.

Comment: Ahhhhh, this is exactly what im after ... well then, bitbucket it is for me .. Thanks alot :)