# Jenkins compile project automatically after change on master branch

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

Hi I am new on jenkins and I have some problems when I try to compile automatically my project (repos are on git). I was able to set compilation only to master branch but I am not able to make automatical this step.
I want that my project automatically compile when I make a new release. 
This is my option panel.
Someone could help me?
Thanks[image]

Comment: You just configured the repo where Jenkins will get your project from. If you want to compile your project etc. the easiest way to do this is with a Jenkinsfile in a declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Suspecting from your Screenshots you are Using Git from within TFS. If you want to trigger your Jenkins Job after a Push or Merge on a branch, you need a git hook which triggers the Jenkins Job. For this you need the Git Plugin and another plugin which can handle the calling Git hook from TFS. You have already installed both (that's what I guess depending on your Screenshot).

Inside Jenkins you need to enable "Build when a change is ushed to TFS/Team Services". Additionally you need to add a hook inside TFS/Team Services.

How to add a Hook to TFS see: [How to trigger jenkins build when changes are commited to TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971227/how-to-trigger-jenkins-build-when-changes-are-commited-to-tfs)

Comment: HI, I use git from Bitbucket, not from TFS

Comment: Then use the [Bitbucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) and follow the answer of sarcosand from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802432/build-jenkins-job-when-push-code-to-bitbucket

Comment: Se stai usando Bitbucket , hai bisogno di WEBHOOK (This will make you jenkin triggered on every push or commit you make to your master or any other branch you specify). Vedi questo https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/tutorial-create-and-trigger-a-webhook-747606432.html

Comment: I read the sarcosand guided, installed the plugin and created the bitbucket-hook/ but nothings happend. In order to obtain a public ip i used ngrok..