# jenkins hook not working - jenkins bitbucket

Tags: java, git, jenkins, hook, bitbucket

Hi i am using jenkins and bitbucket , i want to trigger a build in jenkins when ever i commit any thing to bitbucket repository .

**in jenkins**

- i created a project called `test_1`
- in configure section `Build Triggers` part i ticked `Trigger builds remotely`
- i added a token `TEST_TOKEN`

when i type this in my browser url and execute the jenkins build is triggered

```
http://test.com:8080/job/test_1//build?token=TEST_TOKEN
```

**In bitbucket**

i added a `jenkins hook`

- Endpoint : http://test.com:8080/job/test_1//build?token=TEST_TOKEN
- Module name - empty
- Project name - test_1
- Token - empty

then commited some code to bitbucket via git , The jenkins build not running , seems that the trigger is not running . :/ how to solve this problem . please help me . thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have the wrong endpoint - it should be the url of your jenkins instance, not the job url. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+hook+management

Comment: Take a look at this answer I wrote a while back, it may give you more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18538247/1971120

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. @fmitchell is correct with his suggestions for these fields.
But it didn't work for me.

I use a normal POST Hook instead where I provide the whole URL:

```
http://USER_NAME:USER_TOKEN@YOUR.JENKINS.URL.COM:YOUR_PORT/job/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/build?token=some_token_from_jenkins

eg: http://bob.miller@jenkins.example.com:8080/job/test_1/build?token=TEST_TOKEN
```

It seems to be that Bitbuckt is missing the last parameter "build" in its created URL, but I can't tell for sure.

**------Update------**

I found a better solution, where you don't only trigger your build but also be able do build different branches by different Jenkins projects:

- Install [Bitbucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) at your Jenkins
- Add a normal Post as Hook to your Bitbucket repository (*Settings -> Hooks*) and use following url:

> https://*YOUR.JENKINS.SERVER:PORT*/bitbucket-hook

- Configure your Jenkins project as follows:

  - under **build trigger** enable **Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket**
  - under **Source Code Management** select **GIT**; enter your credentials and define **Branches to build** (like ***feature/**)

By this way I have three build projects, one for all features, one for develop and one for release branch.

And best of it, you don't have to ad new hooks for new Jenkins projects.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

Endpoint : http://test.com:8080/
Module name: 
Project name: test_1
Token: TEST_TOKEN