# Bitbucket hook doesn't arrive in Jenkins mac

Tags: ios, xcode, git, jenkins, bitbucket

This question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845593/jenkins-hook-not-working-jenkins-bitbucket) . I feel that I missing something small. What did I do:
1.Installed Jenkins. (without jenkins user just to avoid moving all the ssh between users).
**Jenkins**
 1/a I installed all the necessary plugins (git plugin...)
 1/b Set my build with git repository and a key
 1/c Jenkins global Security Jenkins own data enabled and Any one can do anything selected.
 1/d in configuration system Jenkins url set http://extrnalIp:8081/
 1/e I can build my project its get cloned from bit Bucket and build itself.
**Router**
 I set port forawrding to 8081 so it will not interfere with 8080.
  1/a before moving to port forwarding I tried it with usual port 8080.
**BitBucket**
In the hook section I tried the following options.
1/a http://username:30df7f2e47fd262225b3ca3519388959@externalIP:8081/
projectname:TestHook, token: someToken.
1/b POST:http://userName:30df7f2e47fd262225b3ca3519388959@externalIP:8081/job/TestHook/build?token=someToken 
1/c I followed bitbucket explanation (as some references which I found on the web)... bitbucket troubleshooting dint help me too much. 
some other options which I already don't remember.

I push something to my repository but the Hook never get triggered.
I set a packet sniffer but I see nothing come to the port 8081.

can somebody advise me what can be the problem or what to try.
I am new to Jenkins.

Tnx A lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I finished with setting down **Poll SCM** in project configuration with schedule:

```
*/1 * * * *
```

every minute.