# git server side 'update' hook in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, githooks

I'm looking for way to create a git server side push hook (will be used to enforce referencing JIRA ticket number in each commit message).

According to [pro git - git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), the git hook to use on the server side is 'update', which exists on .git/hooks dir.
Since I'm using BitBucket for git hosting, I need to somehow send this file to the .git/hooks dir in the site.

Using [BitBucket services](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Managing+Bitbucket+Services) will not be suitable, since they are 'post-receive' hooks, so there's no point in using existing or writing my own broker, therefore [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107320/create-a-bitbucket-git-commit-hook) doesn't give me a proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apparently, it is not possible, according to the answer I got at [answers.atlassian.com](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/165991/enable-an-update-hook-in-bitbucket-git-repository?page=1#166491).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Bitbucket Server doesn't provide an API or UI to install an `update` hook. It only supports `pre-receive` and `post-receive` hooks on that level. However, since Bitbucket Server uses a generic `git` at the backend, it is indeed possible to install any of the standard git hooks.

This approach requires filesystem access with admin/root rights to the host where Bitbucket Server is installed.

The hooks are located in `shared/config/git/template/hooks` and are automatically copied inside per-repository hooks directory when you create a new repository. To install a custom hook for an existing repository, do that in `shared/data/repositories/<repo_number>/hooks`.

I have created a ready to use solution for validating the commit log against a configurable JIRA host using a configurable username and password. The solution verifies the following:

- Conformance to Linux kernel style log formatting (50/72 rule)
- Presence of a JIRA issue key in the summary
- JIRA issue assignee's e-mail matching the committer's e-mail
- JIRA issue status being 'In Progress'

You can download the files here:
https://github.com/AlexanderAmelkin/bitbucket-git-hooks-for-jira

For portability, the main validation script is written in Javascript for node.js that is available both for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score -2):

I far I know JIRA now integrates with Bitbucket. All you need is a [JIRA Bitbucket plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-bitbucket-connector-plugin)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the suggested plugin does not enforce commit messages. It only links commit messages which contains JIRA ticket number, with the relevant JIRA ticket.